# OpenERP Set default filter from back end

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

In openeducat model after click a menu item I want to load timetable records as filtered by state, where state equals postponed.
-using xml or python code. & here is my xml view.

```
<menuitem id="menu_op_timetable" 
          parent="menu_op_timetable_main" 
          name="View Time Table"
          sequence="20" 
          action="act_open_op_timetable_view" />

<record id="view_op_timetable_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">op.timetable.form</field>
        <field name="model">op.timetable</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="8" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Time Table" version="7.0">
                <header>
                    <button name="action_complete" string="Complete" type="workflow" icon="gtk-apply" states="planned,postponed"/>
                    <button name="action_postponed" string="Postponed" type="workflow" icon="gtk-jump-to" states="planned,postponed"/>
                    <button name="action_cancel" string="Cancel" type="workflow" icon="gtk-cancel" states="planned,postponed"/>
                            <!--class="oe_button oe_form_button oe_highlight oe_form_visible" -->
                    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" readonly="True" statusbar_colors='{"r":"red"}'
                            statusbar_visible="planned,postponed,completed,cancelled"/>
                </header>
                <sheet>
                    <separator colspan="4" string="Time Table" />
                    <group colspan="4" col="4">
                        <field name="faculty_id" />
                        <field name="standard_id" />
                        <field name="division_id" />
                        <field name="period_id" />
                        <field name="subject_id" />
                        <field name="classroom_id" />
                        <field name="start_datetime" />
                        <field name="end_datetime" />
                        <field name="type"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First need to add filter in search view filter of object `op.timetable` like

```
<filter string="Postponed" name="state_postponed" domain="[('state','=','postponed')]" icon="terp-document-new"/>
```

Action id is `act_open_op_timetable_view` and edit and add default filter like

```
<field name="context">{'search_default_state_postponed': 1}</field>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

**EDIT:**

If you want to restrict other state record than we need to use in domain.

Action id is `act_open_op_timetable_view` and edit below domain like

```
<field name="domain">[('state','=','postponed')]</field>
<field name="context">{}</field>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Odedra.. It is working.. But I close the filter It will able to see all records. What I want is, in this view I only want to load postponed records.

Comment: i edited my answer you may try with it. i hope that will solved your problem. Thanks